# Unable to Call Function nested inside ngOnInit

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

What I want to achieve is when I press the button it will retrieve the first name in the console, however I am having problem calling the firstname function from .ts to .html file via button.
The UI can be seen here .
[image]

In .ts file the grabfirst() function is unable to reach  this.getFirst.
(Basically anything inside Edit_Pro is unreachable )

**editprofile.page.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {actions} from "src/app/reduxStore/auth/user";

import {UserStateFormatted} from "src/app/typings";
import {isNilOrIsEmpty} from "src/app/utilities";
import {findNamespaceOfIdentifier} from "@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/commonjs_umd_utils";



// noinspection BadExpressionStatementJS
@Component({
  selector: 'app-editprofile',
  templateUrl: './editprofile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editprofile.page.scss'],
})

export class EditprofilePage implements OnInit {
  public getFirst: Function;

  constructor() {
  }



  public ngOnInit():any {
    type DispatchProps = typeof actions;
    interface StateProps {
      user: UserStateFormatted;
    }
    interface LoginProps extends  StateProps, DispatchProps { }
    const Edit_Pro = (props: LoginProps) => {
      const {
        user,
        updateFirstName,
        updateLastName,
      } = props;

      const {
        sessionId,
        maskedEmail,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phone,
        phoneNumberWithCountryCode,

      } = user;
      const hasEmail = !isNilOrIsEmpty(sessionId) && !isNilOrIsEmpty(email?.email);
      const FullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
      let fn = "";
      let ln = "";
//unable to reach here
      this.getFirst = () => {
        console.log("reached here");
        return firstName;
      }
    }
  }

//trying to call getFirst
  grabFirst() {
console.log(this.getFirst());
  }



}
```

In .html file I have a simple "Grab first name" button but it unable to receive anything.

**editprofile.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Personal <ion-button href="/customersupport"  class="mainstyle">
      <ion-icon name="chatbox-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button></ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content >

//trying to grab firstname
      <ion-button  expand="block" type="submit" (click)="grabFirst()"
                >Grab first name
          </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

When I click the button ,I dont get the first name only the following error

Currently giving error

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: this.getFirst is not a function
    at EditprofilePage.grabFirst (editprofile.page.ts:60)
    at EditprofilePage_Template_ion_button_click_7_listener (template.html:10)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15279)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15317)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:592)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28578)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
```

Hoping anyone can help to properly call the this.getFirst() function and pass those information to the button.

Comment: You haven't called Edit_Pro function. You might want to add Edit_Pro() inside ngOnInit()

Comment: Sadly still the same issue

Comment: Where `getFirst` is? I think you should refactor your code and split it to cleaner moving parts. It's hard to read... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have commented //unable to reach here for this.getFirst  I need to globally call that function outside Edit_Pro.

Comment: Have you tried this.getFirst(){//  code} instead of this.getFirst = () =>{} ... This seems weird, but it might be another writing possiblity I don't know. But your error comes from the fact that getFirst is not considered as a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {actions} from "src/app/reduxStore/auth/user";

import {UserStateFormatted} from "src/app/typings";
import {isNilOrIsEmpty} from "src/app/utilities";
import {findNamespaceOfIdentifier} from "@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/commonjs_umd_utils";



// noinspection BadExpressionStatementJS
@Component({
  selector: 'app-editprofile',
  templateUrl: './editprofile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editprofile.page.scss'],
})

export class EditprofilePage implements OnInit {
  public firstName: any = "";

  constructor() {
  }



  public ngOnInit():any {
    type DispatchProps = typeof actions;
    interface StateProps {
      user: UserStateFormatted;
    }
    interface LoginProps extends  StateProps, DispatchProps { }
    const Edit_Pro = (props: LoginProps) => {
      const {
        user,
        updateFirstName,
        updateLastName,
      } = props;

      const {
        sessionId,
        maskedEmail,
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phone,
        phoneNumberWithCountryCode,

      } = user;
      const hasEmail = !isNilOrIsEmpty(sessionId) && !isNilOrIsEmpty(email?.email);
      const FullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
      let fn = "";
      let ln = "";

      //setting in global variable
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.grabFirst(); //calling method
        
      }
    }
  }

//trying to call getFirst
  grabFirst() {
console.log(this.firstName);
  }



}
```